# How to find if the Url has completed loading inside custom HybridWebview in IOS on Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm working on xamarin forms HCHybridWebview and my objective is to catch the event once the url being loaded completely on IOS. My code as follow.

This part was made according to the Documentation

```
  [assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof(HCHybridWebview), typeof(HCHybridWebviewRendererIos))]
namespace HashChing.iOS.CustomRenderers
   {

    public class HCHybridWebviewRendererIos : ViewRenderer<HCHybridWebview, WKWebView>, IWKScriptMessageHandler
    {
    public StorageService storageService => DependencyService.Get<StorageService>() ?? new StorageService();

    const string JavaScriptFunction = "function invokeCSharpAction(data){window.webkit.messageHandlers.invokeAction.postMessage(data);}";
    WKUserContentController userController;

    protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<HCHybridWebview> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged (e); 

        if (Control == null) {
            userController = new WKUserContentController ();
            var script = new WKUserScript (new NSString (JavaScriptFunction), WKUserScriptInjectionTime.AtDocumentEnd, false);
            userController.AddUserScript (script);
            userController.AddScriptMessageHandler (this, "invokeAction");

            var config = new WKWebViewConfiguration { UserContentController = userController };
            var webView = new WKWebView (Frame, config);
            SetNativeControl (webView);
        }
        if (e.OldElement != null) {
            userController.RemoveAllUserScripts ();
            userController.RemoveScriptMessageHandler ("invokeAction");
            var hybridWebView = e.OldElement as HCHybridWebview;
            hybridWebView.Cleanup ();
        }
        if (e.NewElement != null) {
            var hybridView = e.NewElement as HCHybridWebview;
            if(hybridView != null)
            {
                hybridView.RefreshView += LoadUrl;
            }
            //string fileName = Path.Combine (NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath, string.Format ("Content/{0}", Element.Uri));

        }
     }
```

In the same class this is where I load my URL

```
    public void LoadUrl(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var webview = (HCHybridWebview)sender;
        var req = new NSMutableUrlRequest(new NSUrl(webview.weblink));

        NSMutableDictionary dic = new NSMutableDictionary();
        dic.Add(new NSString("Authorization"), new NSString("Bearer " + storageService.GetData<Token>("Token").token));
        req.Headers = dic;
        Control.LoadRequest(req);

    }

    public void DidReceiveScriptMessage (WKUserContentController userContentController, WKScriptMessage message)
    {
        Element.InvokeAction (message.Body.ToString ());
    }
  }
}
```

Any help would much appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

You can implement it in method **`DidFinishNavigation`**

```
public class HCHybridWebviewRendererIos : ViewRenderer<HCHybridWebview, WKWebView>, IWKScriptMessageHandler,IWKNavigationDelegate

protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<HCHybridWebview> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged (e); 

    if (Control == null) {
        userController = new WKUserContentController ();
        var script = new WKUserScript (new NSString (JavaScriptFunction), WKUserScriptInjectionTime.AtDocumentEnd, false);
        userController.AddUserScript (script);
        userController.AddScriptMessageHandler (this, "invokeAction");

        var config = new WKWebViewConfiguration { UserContentController = userController };
        var webView = new WKWebView (Frame, config);

        webview.WeakNavigationDelegate=this;

        SetNativeControl (webView);
    }
}


[Export("webView:didFinishNavigation:")]
public void DidFinishNavigation(WKWebView webView, WKNavigation navigation)
{
  if(!webView.IsLoading)
  {
     // do some thing you want
  }
}
```

Comment: [Export("webView:didFinishNavigation:")]
public void DidFinishNavigation(WKWebView webView, WKNavigation navigation)
{
  if(!webView.IsLoading)
  {
     // do some thing you want
  }
} .   exactly where do i paste this code

Comment: in your custom renderer